# Numbering appendices by letter instead of number

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

I'm trying to get a hold of numbering the letter of the appendices. This is how it looks now:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}        

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\appendix
\section{Appendices}
\subsection{First appendix}
\subsection{Second appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image: Preview]
But instead of counting the numbers

> A.1
> A.2
> ...

I want to the letters to be increased. It should be something like this:

> Appendices
> A - first appendix
> B - second appendix
> C - third appendix

where "Appendices" is a section, and the other are subsections.

I hope that anyone can help me :)

Comment: I have a similar problem, in the appendix section letter and Arabic numbers get mixed up, the first appendix gets a letter and the remaining appendices get Arabic numbers.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you really need the appendices to be subsections you can change numbering of subsections using `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\appendix
\section*{Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

\subsection{Appendix Subsection}
\subsection{Another appendix Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking after! Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I try to use your answer, I run into two issues: firstly, I receive the error _"No counter 'chapter' defined."_ on the line `\appendix` even though my document class is set to _article_, so there shouldn't be any chapters at all. If I remove that line, my document compiles, but my appendices added as subsections start from C rather than A (I have 2 subsections in my last section in the document). If I use `\setcounter{subsection}{0}`, they start from A but the page numbering gets flawed in the table of contents

Answer (score 22):

Use `\section*{Appendices}`and add this to the toc with `\addcontentsline`. Then simply use `\section` for each appendix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\section*{Appendices}
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: I don't think it clearly solves my problem, that the appendices A, B ect. should be subsections of Appendices. Do you know how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Solved in  Tahtisilma's answer :)

Comment: is there a way of doing this, but getting 1. First appendix 2. Second appendix?

Comment: @canIchangethis Change `\appendix` by `\setcounter{section}{0}`,  but  then are not appendices, but duplicated sections ...

Comment: Thanks. I made a new question cause I think my problem is „more“ than just that but will try!

Answer (score 12):

I find it easier to simply use:

```
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A}
```

and just change it for each appendix:)

Comment: You could do that of course, but there **are** better ways -- I leave to others to deal with this answer

Comment: Solved my problem since i'm using only one chapter for the appendix and the numbering didn't work at all (for the chapter). The 'A' for the chapter just stands for *A*ppendix and every subsection is numbered with A.1, A.2, ... and so on.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me, and I am using `\thesection`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

\section*{A: Section heading}

OR

\section*{Section A: Section heading}

OR

\section*{Part A: Section heading}

Comment: While this may give a result that looks like a solution, it's not a good idea to short-circuit LaTeX and to manually do the work that LaTeX should be doing. It's better to use a package for this, or use a macro. The previous answers already covered this completely.