# Appendix: chapter from A,B,C to A1, A2 A3

Tags: numbering, chapters, appendices

I'm trying to match my supervisor's requirements for the appendix formatting. I'm using the scrbook- and appendix-package. Right now my chapters are numbered by letters A,B,C and the sections then by A.1, A.2, etc.
I want it to be A1, A2, A3 for chapters and sections should be A1.1, A1.2, etc.

I saw many ways to change the chapter's formatting but I never saw the one I'd like to have. Are there any hints how to get there?

Cheers!
Julian

Comment: In case anyone else has the opposite problem, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174621/numbering-appendices-by-letter-instead-of-number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by re-defining the `\thechapter` after appendix:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\arabic{chapter}}
```

but then in toc, the spaces get messed up. To correct this, load `tocloft` and and adjust the spaces:

```
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em}
\cftsetindents{section}{2em}{2.4em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{4.4em}{3.2em}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em}
\cftsetindents{section}{2em}{2.4em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{4.4em}{3.2em}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Some chapter}
  \section{Asection}
  \appendix
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\arabic{chapter}}
  \chapter{Some appendix}
  \section{section in appendix}
  \chapter{Some appendix again}
  \section{section in appendix again}
  \section{section in appendix again}
  \subsection{sub section in appendix again}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by using

`\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\arabic{chapter}` in the `appendices` environment.

Since the counter output for `section` is normally based on `\thechapter.\arabic{section}` etc., the new definition for `\thechapter` will be used there too.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\arabic{chapter}}

\chapter{First appendix chapter}

\section{First}
\section{Two}


\chapter{Second appendix chapter}

\section{First}
\section{Two}

\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

[image]