# Adding A B after word appendices in TOC also shows the letter in sections and tables

Tags: appendices

My problem is that I have a template for my thesis . I was planning to add appendices to my work. The appendices are tables in a separate .tex file.

What I did is that.

I included the Package :

```
 %  Appendix
 \usepackage[titletoc, title]{appendix}
```

at the end of the main.tex file I called the appendices as

```
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Energy per job}
  \include{ChaptersStructure/Tables/EnergyPerjob2}
  \include{ChaptersStructure/Tables/Table_TotalEnergyAll}
\end{appendices}
```

unfortunately, the letter A or B did not show for tables or sections. the output of the appendices in the following picture:

[image]

Also, the TOC does not show the Letter A or B

[image]

Can I find any help with this issue?

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: This could help you : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174621/numbering-appendices-by-letter-instead-of-number